# Open a frame, not a tab when open a doc with Aquamacs command line

Tags: emacs, aquamacs

Aqumacs has a command line name 'aquamacs', and I can use this command to launch the Aquamacs without using 'open -a Aquamacs'.

The thing is that when Aquamacs is already running, calling 'aquamacs' opens a tab in the preexisting frame.

Can I change this behavior? Can I open a new frame not a new tab?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Aquamacs, but this is what I do with standard emacs:

```
emacsclient -n -e '(raise-frame (select-frame (make-frame-command)))'
```

You can make that a shell alias, a shell script or bind it to a hotkey or something similar.